# how to ask GPS permission and after finish show map

Tags: android, google-maps

I m working on map and i m new in map . i m displaying map(v1) and  working perfect but my problem is marshmallow i have to ask run time permition i m displaying  permition dialog runtime but  after permit-ion display same time map is also displaying and crashing because after display permission-dialog map location   working even i dint  permit my question is i want display map if permission granted without permeation always ask permission.
my code is.

```
     public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

GoogleMap googleMap;
String username, password;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
SessionManager session;
Location location;
String bestProvider;
LocationManager locationManager;

;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION = 111;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplication(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MapsActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

        } else {

            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                    MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION);

            // MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION is an
            // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
            // result of the request.
        }
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        buildAlertMessageNoGps();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);

    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
    password = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);



    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_FINE_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
//    LatLng initialLoc= googleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

    //   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));*/
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(60));

//    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng); //Store these lat lng values somewhere. These should be constant.
    CameraUpdate location1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            latLng, 20);
    googleMap.animateCamera(location1);




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.notify_setting:
            new Logout().execute();
            return true;
        case R.id.changepassword:
            Intent nextscreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Changepassword.class);
            startActivity(nextscreen);
            return true;

    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}

class Logout extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Wait For Logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        //pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
        //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        //pDialog.show();


    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        if (AllChanges.checkinternet()) {
            // Building Parameters

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(AllChanges.Url + "?r=api/getresponse&model=gpslogout&type=logout",
                    "POST", params);

            if (json != null) {
                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt("success");

                    if (success == 1) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                session.logoutUser();

                                cancelAlarmManager();
                                finish();

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Try After Some Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done


    }

}

public void cancelAlarmManager() {
    Log.d("hi", "cancelAlarmManager");
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    Intent gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("currentlyTracking", false);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
}

private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
    private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

    private static final int REQUEST = 112;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
        } else {
            //call get location here
        }
    } else {
        //call get location here
    }
```

get Permissions Result

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        //call get location here
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to access your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

getLocation

```
    public void getLocation()
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
    }
```